# updating records in sugarcrm through soap API

Tags: soap, sugarcrm

**What I have Done?**

when i  add a content from drupal it appear in sugarcrm , this can be done by set_entry.

**what i want?**

when I edit data in drupal it reflect on sugarcrm and also it`s vice versa.

**facing prblem?**

I don`t how It can be done, weither a function like set_entry is present to update data or not
in soap api of sugarcrm.

**please give me suggestion.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by doing:-

1. create the file in **custom/Extension/modules/YOUR_MODULE/Ext/Vardefs/customGlobalSearchFields.php.**

add code

```
<?php

$dictionary['YOUR_MODULE']['fields']['NAME_OF_FIELD_TO_SEARCH']['unified_search'] = true;
```

1. create file in   ****custom/modules/YOUR_MODULE/metadata/SearchFields.php.**

add code:-

```
<?php

$searchFields['YOUR_MODULE']['NAME_OF_FIELD_TO_SEARCH'] = array( 'query_type'=>'default');
```

then finally do a quick rebuild and repair, and the field should now be available to be searched thru the global search.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a set_entry exists and the documentation can be found at [sugarCRM api documentation](http://apidocs.sugarcrm.com/api/6.5.0/ce/)

A call via smalltalk/javascript to the rest version of the api would look like:

```
setEntryFor: aModule values: aNameValueList do: aBlock
| params |
params := Dictionary new
        at: 'session' put: self sessionId;
        at: 'module_name' put: aModule;
    at: 'name_value_list' put: aNameValueList;
    yourself.

jQuery 
    ajax: self url,'rest.php'
    options: #{
    'jsonp' -> 'jsoncallback'.
    'data'-> (HashedCollection new 
    at: 'method' put: 'set_entry';
    at: 'input_type' put: 'JSON';
```

The soap api uses the same structure as the rest api.

Comment: @paul Thanks for reply . Actually my update  start working on  module of sugarcrm, like Accounts. this can be done by seach_by_module method to get the id , then we simply update data  from set_entry. now my problem is search_by_module does not search result on custom module. that was created with module builder by me.